# Qtimer and closing out an applicaiton

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

## So, I have this code.

I open this window from another by a button, I need only this to be closed by a timer(QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)). But according to the timer, two windows are currently closing.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer,QDateTime, pyqtSignal, QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from content import Ui_content

class Ui_cityquestion1(object):

    def setupUi(self, cityquestion1):
        cityquestion1.setObjectName("cityquestion1")
        cityquestion1.resize(1223, 800)
        cityquestion1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.task = QtWidgets.QLabel(cityquestion1)
        self.task.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1231, 81))

        self.task.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.task.setObjectName("task")
        self.answer1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer1.clicked.connect(self.yes)
        # self.answer1.clicked.connect(QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        self.answer1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 520, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer1.setFont(font)

        self.answer1.setObjectName("answer1")
        self.answer2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 520, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer2.setFont(font)
  
        self.answer2.setObjectName("answer2")
        self.answer3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 650, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer3.setFont(font)

        self.answer3.setObjectName("answer3")
        self.answer4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cityquestion1)
        self.answer4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(690, 650, 291, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Shell Dlg 2")
        font.setPointSize(24)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.answer4.setFont(font)
        self.answer4.setObjectName("answer4")

        self.start = True
        self.count = 5
        self.timeryes = QTimer()
        self.timerno = QTimer()
        self.timerno.timeout.connect(self.no)
        self.timeryes.timeout.connect(self.yes)

        self.labelf = QtWidgets.QLabel(cityquestion1)
        self.labelf.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 0))

        self.labelf.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelf.setObjectName("labelf")

        self.labelyes = QtWidgets.QLabel(cityquestion1)
        self.labelyes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 0, 0))

        self.labelyes.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.labelyes.setObjectName("labelyes")

        self.retranslateUi(cityquestion1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(cityquestion1)

        self.retranslateUi(cityquestion1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(cityquestion1)

    def retranslateUi(self, cityquestion1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        cityquestion1.setWindowTitle(_translate("cityquestion1", "Form"))
        self.labelf.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Nespravne !"))
        self.labelyes.setText(_translate("cityquestion1", "Spravne !"))

    def yes(self):
        self.start = True
        self.timeryes.start(1000)
        self.labelyes.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1223, 800))
        self.labelyes.show()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, QtCore.QCoreApplication.quit)
        if self.start == True:
            self.count -= 1
        if self.count <= 1:
            self.answer1.clicked.disconnect(self.yes)
            self.timeryes.stop()
            self.start = False
            self.count = -1
            print(self.count)

    def ye(self):
        cityquestion1.hide()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    cityquestion1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_cityquestion1()
    ui.setupUi(cityquestion1)
    cityquestion1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear and your code confusing. What do you mean by "according to the timer, two windows are currently closing"? Also, if you only want to close a window, you should not call `QApplication.quit()`. Be aware that you are not supposed to edit pyuic generated files (as written in the header comment you ignored and removed), but instead follow the guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: So, I open this window above with the help of another one, how can I use the timer, for example, to close exactly this window

Comment: It would be `QTimer.singleShot(3000, somewindow.close)`. But that `somewindow` must be a *QWidget* instance, which would be `cityquestion1` in the context of the above code; unfortunately, that would not be valid if called from outside of `setupUi()` *and* from another script, because the `cityquestion1` reference created in the final part of that code will not be executed in that case. That is a further reason for which these files should *not* be edited, as it makes things unnecessarily complex. The only proper way to use pyuic classes is explained in the link above.